# Как отобразить изображение в html

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, img, ejs

Я пишу приложение. Сервер на express.js, за отображение отвечает шаблонизатор ejs, хранение данных в Mongodb.
По стеку я принимаю картинку и данные по ней и сохраняю все в Mongodb. Изображение тоже.
Потом я должен отобразить картинку на веб странице.
Но тут получается что я получаю картинку как битовый массив и не знаю как ее передать в ejs (в html) чтобы картинка нормально отобразилась. Можно написать дополнительный роутер, чтобы он отдавал картинки по запросу, как статические объекты. Но тогда получится, что на странице, где будет 100 изображений я буду делать 100 запросов в бд.
Сохранять картинки как файлы в файловой системе тоже не вариант, да и хочется научиться работать с файлами таким образом.
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: У вас изображение же хранится в base64, верно?